# Obtener un dato especifico en Firestore/Firebase (Web/Javascript)

Tags: javascript, firebase, web

En la documentacion de firebase/firestore te explican como leer TODOS los datos de un colección.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no he encontrado ningún lugar donde te expliquen como obtener un documento especifico de una colección de datos.

¿Cómo podría obtener un documento especifico de una colección?

Por ejemplo: 
Si en la colección datos_usuario hay dos documentos que son el user1 y el user2, y por cada documento se guardan: nombre, apellido, email.

Si yo quiero unicamente de la colección, datos_usuario, del documento user2 traer solo el nombre ¿Cómo lo haría?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que tienes que hacer es muy simple, la función `doc` te permite acceder a una ruta específica del documentó al cual quieres acceder, de esta forma:

```
var database = firebase.firestore();
database.doc('mycollection/mydocument').onSnapshot(function(result) {
  var data = result.data();
  console.log(data);
})
```

Y si lo que quiere es guardar datos en el documento, solo harías esto:

```
var database = firebase.firestore();
database.doc('mycollection/mydocument').set({
  username: 'Pablo',
  age: 18
})
```